# Android 10 (api-29) file writing

Tags: android, file, permissions, android-permissions

Can anyone provide an accurate tutorial on how to save files on Android Q publicily available, since [getExternalFilesDir()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getExternalFilesDir(java.lang.String)) is unavailable to use in Android Q+.

I've been dealing with this issue for some days, and can't figure out any solution.

I am trying to download some css, js, and HTML files for loading them on a Webview.

Right now, I have the following code, written in Kotlin:

```
companion object {
    private const val TAG = "MainActivity"
    private var rootDir: Path? = null
}

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    ...

    rootDir = getExternalFilesDir(null)
    Log.v(TAG, "RootDir: ${rootDir!!.path}")

    val cacheDir = File(rootDir!!, "cache")
    if(!cacheDir.exists()) {
         Log.v(TAG, "Creating cache dir (${cacheDir.path})")
         try {
            if (cacheDir.mkdirs())
                Log.v(TAG, "Created cache dir correctly")
            else
                Log.v(TAG, "Could not create cache dir")
        }catch (ex: IOException){
            Log.e(TAG, "Could not create cache dir: ", ex)
        }catch (ex: SecurityException) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Not allowed to create cache dir: ", ex)
        }
    }

    val cssDir = File(cacheDir, "css")
    if(!cssDir.exists()){
        Log.v(TAG, "Creating css dir (${cssDir.path})")
        try {
            if (cacheDir.mkdirs())
                Log.v(TAG, "Created css dir correctly")
            else
                Log.v(TAG, "Could not create css dir")
        }catch (ex: IOException){
            Log.e(TAG, "Could not create css dir: ", ex)
        }catch (ex: SecurityException) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Not allowed to create css dir: ", ex)
        }
    }

    val siteGlobal = File(cssDir, "site_global.css")
    if(!siteGlobal.exists())
        DownloadFileAsyncTask().execute(DownloadFileAsyncTask.DownloadArgs("...", siteGlobal.path))
}
```

And DownloadFileAsyncTask:

```
    private class DownloadFileAsyncTask :
        AsyncTask<DownloadFileAsyncTask.DownloadArgs, Int, Void?>() {

        data class DownloadArgs(val url : String, val savePath : String)

        override fun doInBackground(vararg downloadFiles: DownloadArgs?): Void? {
            for(downloadFile in downloadFiles) {
                val urlStr = downloadFile!!.url
                val outputFilePath = downloadFile.savePath
                val outputFile = File(outputFilePath)
                val url = URL(urlStr)

                Log.v(TAG, "Connecting...")
                val connection = url.openConnection() as HttpURLConnection
                connection.connect()

                if (connection.responseCode != HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
                    throw InterruptedException("Server returned HTTP ${connection.responseCode} ${connection.responseMessage}")
                }

                Log.v(TAG, "Connection correct")
                if (!outputFile.exists()) {
                    Log.v(TAG, "Creating ${outputFile.path}")
                    outputFile.createNewFile()
                }

                val fileLength = connection.contentLength

                val input = connection.inputStream
                val output = FileOutputStream(outputFile)

                val data = ByteArray(4096)
                var total: Long = 0
                var count: Int
                Log.v(TAG, "Starting download...")
                while (true) {
                    count = input.read(data)
                    if (count < 0) break
                    total += count
                    if (fileLength > 0)
                        publishProgress((total * 10 / fileLength).toInt())
                    output.write(data, 0, count)
                }

                output.close()
                input?.close()
                connection.disconnect()
            }

            return null
        }
    }
```

And my response on Logcat is:

```
V/MainActivity: RootDir: /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/.../files
V/MainActivity: Creating cache dir (/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/.../files/cache)
V/MainActivity: Created cache dir correctly
V/MainActivity: Creating css dir (/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/.../files/cache/css)
V/MainActivity: Could not create css dir
V/MainActivity: Connecting...
V/MainActivity: Connection correct
V/MainActivity: Creating /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/.../files/cache/css/site_global.css
```

And obviously, it crashes with `java.io.IOException: No such file or directory` at `outputFile.createNewFile()` in AsyncTask, since the directory doesn't exist.

Since no error on the folder creation is shown, it only tells that the directory couldn't be created, I don't know what am I doing wrong.

I've added and granted `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />` in case of it was the issue, and it didn't solve anything.

Comment: "since getExternalFilesDir() is unavailable to use in Android Q+" -- `getExternalFilesDir()` is definitely available for use on Android Q+.

Comment: CommonsWare But I amb still not able to create any directories nor files by using `getExternalFilesDir(null)`, for example.

Comment: Nothing changed about `getExternalFilesDir()` on Android 10. It works the same as it has since it was added in Android 4.4. It works using standard Java file I/O, such as `File` and `OutputStream`. You might consider editing your question and providing a [mcve] showing what you tried and explaining your symptoms **in detail**.

Comment: FWIW, [this sample Java app](https://gitlab.com/commonsguy/cw-jetpack-java/tree/v0.5/ContentEditor) and [its Kotlin equivalent](https://gitlab.com/commonsguy/cw-jetpack-kotlin/tree/v0.5/ContentEditor) show the use of `getExternalFilesDir()`.

Comment: CommonsWare I've now added my code

Comment: Your code does not match your output, as there should be something between the two two output lines showing the success or failure of your `cacheDir.mkdir()` call. I recommend that you switch from `mkdir()` to `mkdirs()`. I also recommend that you stop using string concatenation to create filesystem paths. IOW, replace `val cacheDir = File(rootDirPath!! + "/cache")` with `val cacheDir = File(getExternalFilesDir(), "cache")`.

Comment: CommonsWare I've updated the post with your suggesions, and everying does the same. The `cache` folder is created correctly, that's why on the previous console output it didn't show up, the issue comes when creating the `cache/css` folder.

Comment: Personally, I would skip most of that code. Just call `cacheDir.mkdirs()`, as it creates all parent directories, ignoring those that already exist. Everything that you do before that is just duplicating work that `mkdirs()` will do. And you might want to use the Device File Explorer in Android Studio, or `adb shell ls`, to see whether your directories are being created.

Comment: CommonsWare OMG found the frckn issue. It was just a stupid copy-paste error. I was calling `cacheDir.mkdirs()` in the cssDir creation process. So `cssDir.mkdirs()` was obviously never created. Sorry for being this stupid . Really thank you

Comment: I am facing a similar problem with API29. still not solved.cant able to create folder or files

Answer (score 6):

`getExternalStorageDirectory()` is deprected in API-29

**Check the step**

1. Download and upload file from webserver "Using FTP connection. (It is a way but the not only way)

[How to download a file from FTP server to Android device?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24605622/how-to-download-a-file-from-ftp-server-to-android-device)

2. Save it to external storage

```java
    //private static void createFile(Context ctx, String fileName, byte text)
    private static void createFile(Context ctx, String fileName, String text) {
        File filesDir = ctx.getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOCUMENTS);
        assert filesDir != null;
        if (!filesDir.exists()){
           if(filesDir.mkdirs()){
            }
        }
        File file = new File(filesDir, fileName);
        try {
            if (!file.exists()) {
                if (!file.createNewFile()) {
                    throw new IOException("Cant able to create file");
                }
            }    
            OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(file);
            byte[] data = text.getBytes();
            os.write(data);
            os.close();
            Log.e("TAG", "File Path= " + file.toString());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }    
    }
```

3. Use load URL to load files in webview and inject like this question [Android Web-View : Inject local Javascript file to Remote Webpage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21552912/android-web-view-inject-local-javascript-file-to-remote-webpage) and [Android - How to inject custom css into external webpage in webview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8741735/android-how-to-inject-custom-css-into-external-webpage-in-webview)